# How to send formatted print statement to shell command line?

Tags: bash, shell

I have this bash script which prints out ~800 commands I would like to run on the command line:

```
paste abyss_names.txt abyss_quast.txt | while IFS="$(printf '\t')" read -r f1 f2
do
       printf 'python /quast-2.3/quast.py -o %s %s \n' "$f1 $f2"
done
```

How do I send the print output directly to the unix shell command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `printf`. Just execute the command directly in the loop.

Try this script:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r f1 f2; do
       python /quast-2.3/quast.py -o "$f1" "$f2"
done < <(paste abyss_names.txt abyss_quast.txt)
```

Comment: `python /quast-2.3/quast.py -o file1 /path/to/file1`, where file1 is from abyss_names.txt and the path is from abyss_quast.txt

Comment: Then `python /quast-2.3/quast.py -o "$f1" "$f2"` should have worked right?

Comment: Ah, it does work. Sorry about that. Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
paste abyss_names.txt abyss_quast.txt | while IFS="$(printf '\t')" read -r f1 f2
do
       $(printf 'python /quast-2.3/quast.py -o %s %s \n' "$f1 $f2")
done
```

Comment: `$(...)` is not needed as it will fork a sub-shell for every line in the loop and pipe after `paste` can also be avoided.